# Can anyone tell me how to add fields in drupal webform result?

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

The Defalult fields are #,SUBMITTED,USER,IP ADDRESS...
I need to add an extra field as Deal Title & Expiry which are the fields I have added for my webform, can anyone suggest a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a module named - [Webform MySQL View](http://drupal.org/project/webform_mysql_views/)

Steps:-

- Enable the module
- URL: Base_URL/admin/content/webform/mysql
- Click the MySQL Views tab
- Check the boxes next to the names of the Webforms for which you want to create MySQL views
- Submit the form.

Once you have created a MySQL view for a given Webform, the view will be automatically updated whenever you add, remove, or reorder the components for that Webform.

Try this, it's easy.